# Vuejs @click event inside tooltip not working

Tags: vue.js, tooltip

I have a image and when you hover it, a tool-tip will appear with a Edit, and Delete Button.

```
<div class="paysmart-tooltip hide">
  <p> Click <a :href="editPendingInactive(student)">here</a> to Edit Request.</p>
  <p> Click <button @click.native="deletePendingInactiveRequest(student)">here</button> to Cancel Request.
```

```
@click.native"deletePendingInactiveRequest(student)" is not firing
```

Comment: nothing complex here. should work fine. are you stopping event propagation somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

`.native` modifiers only work on components, not on normal HTML elements. Remove it.